# How to change the file name after uploading the file name in radeditor in asp .net

Tags: radeditor

i have radEditor in web Project.

i click to image manager in radEditor and upload file by Upload Botton. example my file is "MyFile.jpg". my file save in server path whit name "MyFile.jpg".

i want to Change filename after upload in server and save it. i write FileUpload event :

```
public bool RadEditor1_FileUpload(object sender, string fileName)
{
    string FileNameTemp = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    string strExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileNameTemp);
    FileNameTemp = FileNameTemp + "-" + Guid.NewGuid() + strExtension;
    fileName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.LastIndexOf("/") + 1) + FileNameTemp;
    return true;
}
```

but file save yet whit name "MyFile.jpg".

Comment: What line of code do you expect the filename to change?

Comment: Where is the file actually written to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a FileSystemContentProvider and override the StoreFile method. See this forum for more information: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/editor/reduce-image-file-size.aspx

Best regards
Rumen Jekov